# How to better handle a function in a where clause

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I am using SQL Server 2008R2, and I have been looking into some performance issues with queries I am running. It currently looks something similar to this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE table.id = XX
  AND table.categoryId = dbo.function_get_category_id('category config key');
```

It is obviously a lot more complicated than this (hierarchy, multi-lingual, etc) but this is the basic query. It seems like having a function in the WHERE clause is a known issue for SQL Server but I am at a loss for how to better write this query. I tried this (hoping to cheat it) but did not notice any significant improvement.

```
AND table.categoryId = (SELECT dbo.function_get_category_id(...));
```

I've also looked into attempting to use a JOIN and just placing the function in the ON instead.

Is there any convenient way to rewrite a query to move a function (that is required) out of the WHERE clause without rewriting the function itself?

Comment: Well I wouldn't say 'known isssue' - the real explanation would be 'impossible to optimise'. SQL optimises things based on having some knowledge beforehand about the nature of the data. A UDF makes this impossible. The 'known issue' is application developers turning things into functions without realising the repercussions! Is `function_get_category` particularly complicated?

Comment: Yes, highly. I'v attempted to optimize how it runs and made it a little faster in itself but I think the issue still relates to it being called too many times in the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would improve performance, but I'm assuming this is a scalar and only needs to be resolved once.

```
Declare @categoryID varchar(100)
Set @categoryID = dbo.function_get_category_id('category config key')

SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE table.id = XX
  AND table.categoryId = @categoryID
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I am not sure my implementation will allow this - using BIRT to integrate, and not sure how it handles declared variables in the call.

Comment: Not familiar with BIRT, but perhaps you can "string" the command via the ;  For example:   Declare ...;Set ...;Select....;

Comment: Actually I started trying it out - it does let me use declare. I guess it just cares about the single select and I can do whatever else I want. This is likely going to work for me (roughly 20 categorys that take .01-0.1ms to return) only takes ~15 seconds now versus 5 minutes.